# Onde encontro a dll Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer, visual-studio-2012

Onde posso encontrar a dll `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer` ? Preciso usar em um projeto e não a encontro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode instalar via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/)

Acesse o menu Tools>Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console

E instale o pacote com esse comando:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
```

Comment: Eu já instalei esse pacote @RafaelCabral mas não veio ela .. :(

Comment: Tenta dar um rebuild na sua solution, se não funcionar vai em references, clica com o botão direito, add new reference. e pesquise o nome dela lá pra ver se você encontra